# Exception isn't being picked up in catch

Tags: php

I current have a class that holds this method:

```
public function getUser(
) {
    if (!empty($this->UserName)){
        return $this->UserName;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Empty UserName');
    }
}
```

When I then run this method when the UserName is NOT set, the catch is not picking up the thrown exception, the page just silently dies.

```
try {
    $example = $obj->getUser();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Suggestions? - I have read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and found nothing.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `if (!empty($this->UserName))` with `try/catch`?

Comment: Still silently died after doing this @Script47

Comment: Then `UserName` is not actually empty

Comment: What are your error reporting settings? Running your code works (except for the missing semicolon in the `try` block).

Comment: OH so maybe if I replaced `!empty()` to `!isset()` it would work? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well only if that test was relevant to the situation

Comment: It worked, appreciated! Good point, slow day.. I can't check somethings empty if I haven't set it lol @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, I had to recreate what I assumed would be your class.

```
<?php

class User {
    public $UserName = '';

    public function getUser() {
        if (empty($this->UserName))
            throw new Exception('UserName is empty!');

        return $this->UserName;
    }
}

try {
    $user = (new User())->getUser();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

**Output**

[image]

I can only assume that your variable is not actually empty.

**Notice**

In PHP a string with a space in it is **NOT** classed as empty,

```
var_dump(empty(' ')); // false
```

Unless you [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php),

```
var_dump(empty(trim(' '))); // true
```

**Error Reporting**

If it isn't done so already, enable `error_reporting`,

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Having a slow day -L_- Will mark answer as soon as I can x)

Comment: @KyleThomas no problem.